# Mostrar resultado de un select dependiendo de otro select

Tags: javascript

Desde un select en html estoy consultando a un endpoint que me trae los estados y dependiendo del estado que me seleccione me traiga sus municipios como podria traer esa data en el segundo select muestro mi codigo:

```js
 function onChangeInput(idTextInput, idErrorSpan) {
            switch (idTextInput) {
                case "state":
                    var state_id = document.getElementById("state").value;
                    var path = `api/states/${state_id}/municipalities`;
                    validateFieldRequest(idErrorSpan, idTextInput, path).then(
                        (jsonBody) => {
                            console.log(jsonBody)
                            
                        }
                    );
                    break;
```

```html
 <select name="provincia" id="state" onchange="onChangeInput('state')">
  <option>Estado</option>
            <option value="1">Aguascalientes</option>
            <option value="2">Baja California</option>
            <option value="3">Baja California Sur</option>
            <option value="4">Campeche</option>
            <option value="5">Coahuila de Zaragoza</option>
             </select>
                <select name="municipalities" id=municipalities"">
            <option>Municipio</option>


        </select>
```

con este codigo ya hago llamada al endpoint pero como podria llenar el segundo select con la respuesta que me da el endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pides en sí no es una tarea trivial. Pero básicamente podés agregarle un `eventListener` al `select` de los estados y dependiendo del `value` del `option` podés hacer un request a la API.

Si tuvieras dos Selects:

```js
const stateSelect = document.querySelector("#state");
const citySelect = document.querySelector("#municipalities");
```

Agrégale un `eventListener` al `stateSelect`.

```js
stateSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === "1") {
    // haz request a la API trayendo los municipios
  }
  if (e.target.value === "2") {
    // haz request a la API trayendo los municipios
  }
  if (e.target.value === "3") {
    // haz request a la API trayendo los municipios
  }
});
```

Te recomiendo le des un `value` al option `Estado` así cuando se seleccione esa opción se remuevan las opciones anteriormente generadas.

```js
  <select name="provincia" id="state" onchange="onChangeInput('state')">
   <option value='default'>Estado</option> // <-- agrega `value` default
   // ..demás opciones
  </select>

  if (e.target.value === "default") {
    const opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = "default";
    const content = document.createTextNode("Municipio");
    opt.appendChild(content);
    citySelect.innerHTML = "";
    citySelect.appendChild(opt);
  }
```

El `eventListener` quedarías así entonces

```js
stateSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === "default") {
    const opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = "default";
    const content = document.createTextNode("Municipio");
    opt.appendChild(content);
    citySelect.innerHTML = "";
    citySelect.appendChild(opt);
  }
  if (e.target.value === "1") {
    // haz request a la API trayendo los municipios
  }
  if (e.target.value === "2") {
    // haz request a la API trayendo los municipios
  }
  if (e.target.value === "CA") {
    // haz request a la API trayendo los municipios
  }
});
```

Ya cuando recibas la data puedes recorrer el `Array` de Municipios y agregarlos como opciones al `municipalities` select con una función.

```js
const stateSelect = document.querySelector("#state");
const citySelect = document.querySelector("#municipalities");

const createOptions = (municipio) => {
  const opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.value = municipio.value;
  const content = document.createTextNode(municipio.name);
  opt.appendChild(content);
  return opt;
};

const appendOptions = (options) => {
  citySelect.innerHTML = "";
  options.forEach((o) => citySelect.appendChild(o));
};

stateSelect.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === "default") {
    const opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = "default";
    const content = document.createTextNode("Municipio");
    opt.appendChild(content);
    citySelect.innerHTML = "";
    citySelect.appendChild(opt);
  }
  if (e.target.value === "1") {
    const municipios = fetch(`my-api/municipio/1`)
    const options = municipios.map(createOptions);
    appendOptions(options);
  }
  if (e.target.value === "2") {
    const municipios = fetch(`my-api/municipio/2`)
    const options = municipios.map(createOptions);
    appendOptions(options);
  }
  if (e.target.value === "3") {
    const municipios = fetch(`my-api/municipio/3`)
    const options = municipios.map(createOptions);
    appendOptions(options);
  }
});
```

Tendrás que modificar el código a tu caso específico pero es una implementación inicial. Échale un ojo a [este sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dust-q7dr5v?file=/src/index.js). Puedes prescindir del los `if` statements en el `eventListener`. Pero así es más explícito.